# Traffic graph on /site-analytics uses wrong timeframe

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-analytics

The traffic graph on the new `/site-analytics` page doesn't display the correct timeframe if you select very long time periods.

Steps to reproduce:

- Have 25k reputation or a diamond on Arqade
- Visit https://gaming.stackexchange.com/site-analytics
- Select either private beta, public beta or graduation as starting date, leave the current date as end date
- Observe that the traffic graph only goes until 2013

This only affects the traffic graph, not the other two on the page

Comment: This is due to an unfortunate limitation of the Google analytics core API - a maximum of 1000 rows of data (in this case, one row per day). See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference?hl=en#maxResults - I was not aware of this limitation until investigating this bug.

Comment: @Oded It looks like you can ask for more than 1000 results by adjusting that parameter, though not for more than 10000.

Comment: Ah - I need to read better (or possibly clean my glasses once in a while) - I saw the 10,000 and read it as 1,000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data for the traffic graph comes from Google Analytics.

I did not realize that the API limits the result set to 1000 by default, which is what caused this bug.

I have made a change to ensure we get the complete range, so once the cached results are cleared, the graph should display fully.